# Image collisions in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I created some functions to detect collision. Only my ewasteCollsion works right now but my others don't. For example, once the battery collides with the e-waste an explosion occurs. For my other ones, like the spaceshipCollsion doesn't work. Does anyone know how to fix this issue? (My full code isn't here. I wanted to make it as concise as possible)

````
    if spaceship.colliderect(star):
        shipEats += 1
        return True
    False    


def ewasteCollision(battery, ewaste): #If battery hits ewaste
    global yWastePos
    if battery.colliderect(ewaste):
        #addEwaste()
        yWastePos += 1 #DOESN"T WORK
        return True
    False


def spaceshipCollision(spaceship, ewaste): #If spaceship hits ewaste
    if spaceship.collidrect(ewaste):
        health -= 20
        return True
    False


#=========================IN THE GAME LOOP========================


 if is_battery_on_screen == True: #Collsion with battery and ewaste
            batteryRect = pygame.Rect(x_battery_pos, y_battery_pos, batteryImage.get_width(), batteryImage.get_height()) #Dimensions of battery
            ewasteRect3 = pygame.Rect(xWaste3 + 100, yWaste3, 150, 120) #Dimensions of ewaste
            spaceshipRect = pygame.Rect(x_ship_pos + 22, y_ship_pos, 60, 100) #Dimensions of spaceship
            if ewasteCollision(batteryRect, ewasteRect3) == True: #If its true, ewaste explodes and disappears
                is_battery_on_screen = False
                drawExplosion()
                drawStars() #Stars appear for user to collect                


        if spaceshipCollision == True: #DOES NOT WORK!!
            ewasteRect = pygame.Rect(xWastePos + 100, yWastePos, 150, 120) #Dimensions of ewaste
            spaceshipRect = pygame.Rect(x_ship_pos + 22, y_ship_pos, 60, 100) #Dimensions of spaceship            
            drawScene3() #Goes to game over page


        if starCollsion == True: #DOES NOT WORK!!
            starRect = pygame.Rect(xStarPos + 100, yStarPos, 150, 120) #Dimensions of star
            spaceshipRect = pygame.Rect(x_ship_pos + 22, y_ship_pos, 60, 100) #Dimensions of spaceship               
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, RED, starRect, 5) #Remove once done resizing and figured out collsion dimensions```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not calling your methods, what you're doing is comparing your method (definitions) to booleans.

To call the methods, you have to write:

```
if spaceshipCollision(spaceshipRect, ewasteRect3):
```

and

```
if starCollsion(batteryRect, ewasteRect3): # or whatever rects go here
```

---

There's also a typo in your code:

```
if spaceship.collidrect(ewaste):
```

should be

```
if spaceship.colliderect(ewaste): # notice the 'e'
```

---

Additionally, you should use `return False` in your methods, because just writing `False` and not returning anything will make the methods implicitely return `None`.